# Razer Mouse stays lit up when PC is turned off

Tags: power-management, razer-mouse

I have a Razer gaming mouse which has a really bright red laser light. If I power down the computer (but leave the power outlet on) the mouse still emits light, which is quite annoying.

Any idea how to get the red light to go off when I power down the computer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These mice take their light simply from the USB power, without needing to have the system on. It's on the electrical point of view, there is nothing to turn it off in the mouse itself.

However, there is probably a way to tell your computer to cut the power from USB when it's off. I'm not sure, but it could be from a "USB wake-up" option in the Bios (giving you the possibility to wake up the computer from a USB device). So you could check your Bios about such option eventually.

If not, then it is probably something with your motherboard, and besides turning off the back switch, or unplugging the computer, I don't see a way to fix this.

Answer (score 4):

I also have a Razer mouse and keyboard, both with plenty of lights. Great when gaming in the dark. But when I turn off my computer, the lights are turned off too!

I think the problem is not the mouse but the computer, which doesn't seem to switch off completely. It's likely that it's set to awaken again after you press a key or move the mouse, or something silly like that. Some computers are able to turn themselves on again if commanded to do so from an USB device, thus they leave some power on the USB port. The mouse thus receives power and thus keeps the light on. It doesn't know that your computer is off.

If you've put your computer in sleep mode instead of turning it off completely, this is expected. Otherwise, it could be a BIOS setting that will enable power to the USB devices.

(Btw, this is useful when you're recharging e.g. a TomTom or other rechargable device through your computer!)

Comment: It doesn't charge devices when it's off for me. It's only enough to power those annoying LEDs.

Answer (score 4):

in the synapse program under lighting you can now have the lights turn off when your display is turned off. 
(shutting down the p.c. or putting it to sleep, not just turning off the monitor with the power button unfortunately.)

Comment: this has been on forever for me and doesn't help. i do have powered USB hubs though - in fact I rely on them to charge my phone when my computer is off. but this definitely should still be toggleable via synaptic.

Answer (score 2):

You might use a powered USB port.
For example, the Buffalo BSH4A02 USB Hub gives you maximum control:

[image]

(No idea where it's sold and for how much, though)

Comment: But then are we sure **this** doesn't make any light ? These buttons looks typically like being lighted up when on.

Comment: @Gnoupi: You're absolutely right - that's a serious drawback. Solution: while the mouse is ON the work-table, this can be tucked underneath!

Comment: But then it's not easy to access! And even, the light would make a glow around anyway :)

Comment: I'm flat out of counter-arguments ...

Comment: My "light" argument wasn't really one anyway. These things light up only when on, and the point of such device would be to turn off easily when not using. No light problem, then ;)

Answer (score 1):

There's an option in the Razer Synapse 2.0 software that "turns off lighting when display is off". Give that a try

Answer (score 0):

This answer does not turn your mouse off, but it is what alot of us do to cover all those *beeping* bright LEDs that manufacturers insists on putting in our devices...

... we tape them up, with strong, non-residue, highly-opaque insulating tape, so they'll never see the light of day (pun intended).

From this...

[image]

To this...

[image]

Comment: It's not really a solution to powering off the mouse. I had a transparent mouse that wouldn't power off; I can't really tape the whole mouse, it would be unusable... However, I've also used tape for covering up LEDs. Unfortunately, manufacturers that use powerful LEDs probably don't use their own products.

Comment: Oh, a transparent one... that's tricky, but nothing like disassembling the darn thing and spray-painting the insides of the transparent cover. ;)

Comment: @caliban : watch out for the "image clarity limit". One image, small, to illustrate, is improving quality. Big photos showing a really simple thing are passing this limit, making your post take much more space than it should, according to the information given.

Comment: Also, if the problem is when the computer is off only, I don't think that adding something which lowers the appearance and the feeling is really a solution. In that case, better to put a book over it, for night.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tried it, but this might work:

1. Enter Control Panel / System (Hardware tab on XP).
2. Click Device Manager.
3. Click the + at Universal Serial Bus Controllers.
4. Right-click on the USB device representing your mouse and select Properties.
5. Open the Power Management tab.
6. Check Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power.
7. Click OK.

or it might only work for sleep.

Comment: Tried that and it did not work for me.

Comment: This works only during the system is on, and his problem is without even a system on.

Answer (score 0):

Recently fixed this problem by switching profiles in Razer Synapse 2.0 on mac.

If you open Razer Synapse which is the device manager for Razer mouse products, you can create and change button and lighting profiles. Creating a new profile and checking the 'turn off LED on when monitor is off' checkbox fixes the lighting issue described in this thread.

Comment: Switching what profiles and in what way, and how is that accomplished?  This is more of a "teaser" than an actionable solution.

Comment: This does answer the question, and provide a solution. If you open Razer Synapse which is the device manager for Razer mouse products, you can create and change button and lighting profiles. Creating a new profile and checking the 'turn off LED on when monitor is off' checkbox the lighting issue described in this thread. I'm using a mac.

Comment: @Simmeringc Your comment should be a part of your answer. [Edit](http://superuser.com/posts/1111572/edit) your answer and paste relevant information there. I think you can delete your comment afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Here we have fake razer Mice that will stay lit when the pc is off, real ones automatically turn off

Comment: How do you know that for sure? Please post a reliable source

Answer (score -1):

The mouse light stays on if the pc hasnt turned off properly.
I had the same problems with my mouse but then realized that my pc wasnt turning off properly so i made sure i turned my pc off properly. Try configuring to the last successful checkpoint in boot options and after it turns on and in its normal state turn if off like you would normally do.

Hope this helped !

Edit: when your pc is successfully turned off no current is running through any part of the pc so it wouldnt make sense having your mouse light on.

If you power off your power supply (from the button behind the power supply) and power it back on, the mouse light wont come back on.. which indicates that now your pc turned off.. idk what causes this problem but i realized that turning off your pc by holding down the power button of your pc is really bad and ever since i stopped doing it that way my mouse light turns off with my pc.

Comment: It greatly depends on your definition of "off" whenever there would be no current running through any part of the PC. As an example take the [Gigabyte On/Off-Charge](http://www.gigabyte.com/MicroSite/185/on-off-charge.htm) feature. Indeed it's a bad idea to just hold down the power button as you're not telling your system to shut down but rather just unplug the power chord.